# Google Sheets to transform a table into a nested tree to use Tree Map Chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-lists, flat-file

Trying to transform at flat data format to a nested tree so that i can systematically create a Tree Map chart.  There is a similar post, but it stops at a 2 tier tree and I'd like to solve this for an "n-tier" tree.

The request is how to transform the "F" table on the left to the Tree table on the right using a smart set of Query / Flatten functions? (to be clear, the chart requires the nested format on the right)

[image]

Comment: Please, share the source data so that it will be easier to test solutions according to your requirement!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
={"store","","";query(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(sort(split({
unique(A2:A&"~"&"store"&"~"&match((A2:A),unique(A2:A),0)&"_");
unique(B2:B&"~"&A2:A&"~"&match((A2:A),unique(A2:A),0)&match((B2:B&"~"&A2:A),unique(B2:B&"~"&A2:A),0)&"_");
C2:C&"~"&B2:B&"~"&match((A2:A),unique(A2:A),0)&match((B2:B&"~"&A2:A),unique(B2:B&"~"&A2:A),0)&"x~"&D2:D
},"~"),3,1),counta(C2:C)+counta(unique(A2:A))+counta(arrayformula(unique(filter(A2:A&"~"&B2:B,A2:A<>"")))),4),
"select Col1,Col2,Col4",0)}
```

[image]

however, there is no need to sort the result, if so

```
={"store","","";arrayformula(query(split({ 
unique(A2:A&"~"&"store"); 
unique(B2:B&"~"&A2:A); 
C2:C&"~"&B2:B&"~"&D2:D },"~"),"where Col2 is not null",0))}
```

[image]